# Confused about angular scope. Why does this not function as expected?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is very confusing.. Here is a the fiddler [JSFiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GregL/wdS9n/13/)

Angular.copy works on this sample but causes (RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ) with hot towels datacontext.lookup.setLookups(true) method. Any idea why?

Select U3 from the list and click add.
U3 is removed from selection list (dropdown) and added to selected list.
U3 is removed from the other dropdowns.

So it is globally sharing my "Units" list some how in my real project.

How can I copy the list into the containing scope of the specific controller instance?

I am using HotTowel.Angular template with breeze.js. I'm wondering if the reference to the cached lookup values are being shared. Here are the methods that actually get the data for the Units List.

```
 <!-- the actual item detail controller -->
  (function () {
  'use strict';

  var controllerId = 'itemdetail';

   angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['common', 'datacontext', itemdetail]);

  function itemdetail(common, datacontext) {
    var vm = this;
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(controllerId);


    vm.units = [];
    vm.selectedUnit = undefined;
    vm.selectedUnits = [];


    activate();

    function activate() {
        common.activateController([initLookupValues()], controllerId)
            .then(function () {
               // log('Activated Controller' + controllerId,controllerId,true);
            });
    }


    function initLookupValues() {
        vm.units = datacontext.lookup.refreshUnitLookupCachedData(true);
    }
  }
})();       
 <!-- FROM repository.lookup.js ---->
    function refreshUnitLookupCachedData(includeNullo) {
        var predicate = breeze.Predicate.create('isLookUpValue', '==', true);

        if (includeNullo) {
            predicate = predicate.or(this._predicates.isNullo);
        }

        return this.lookupCachedData.units = this._getAllLocal(entityNames.unit, 'displayOrder', predicate);
    }

<!-- FROM repository.abstract.js -->

    function _getAllLocal(resource, ordering, predicate) {
        return EntityQuery.from(resource)
            .orderBy(ordering)
            .where(predicate)
            .using(this.manager)
            .executeLocally();
    }
```

I have a directive that binds a list of objects to a select dropdown box. Then when a user makes a selection they click the add button and the item is removed from the select list and added to the "selected" list. The user can remove from the selected list and it is placed back in the select list as well.

This select directive is rendered for every object that requires these values using an ng-repeat. Every item in the ng-repeat gets its own instance of another controller.

So if there are 10 objects rendered by the ng-repeat , 10 of these dropdowns will be rendered along with other input controls.

if I select an Item in the first dropdown and add it to the selected list. Every dropdown on the page is changed (item removed from dropdown and added to select list). Even tho each rendered dropdown should be related to a specific controller for that ng-repeat item.

I've done something wrong with the scope but have NO IDEA WHAT.

```
 <section id="admin-view" class="mainbar" data-ng-controller="myItemController as i">
        <section class="matter">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="itemFilter" >
                        <div data-dc-item-filter
                             items="i.itemPartials"
                             selected-item="i.selectedItem"
                             item-filter-text="i.itemSearch"
                             filtered-items="i.filteredItemPartials"
                             use-drop-down="false">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row"                      
                   ng-repeat="itemPartial in i.filteredItemPartials"
                        data-ng-controller="itemdetail as vm" >
                        <div class="widget>
                            <div data-cc-widget-header title="{{itemPartial.name}}" 
                                       allow-collapse="true" 
                                    is-widget-expanded="vm.isWidgetExpanded"></div>
                            <div class="widget-content collapse">
                                <div class="row" data-ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
                                    <div id="solids" class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="widget">
                                            <div data-cc-widget-header 
                                             title="Solid Options"   nested-header="true"
                                                 allow-collapse="true"
                                                 is-widget-expanded="vm.isWidgetExpanded"></div>
                                            <div class="row widget-content">
                                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                                    <div data-dc-lookup-dropdown
                                                         title="Items:"
                                                         items="vm.myList"
                                                         selected-item="vm.selectedItem"
                                                         selected-items="vm.selectedItems">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </section>
```

Here is my directive template html and controller

```
  <select class="form-control"
                        data-ng-options="(item.acronym !== undefined ? item.acronym : item.name) for item in items | filter:{selected: false}"
                        data-ng-model="selectedItem"
                        data-ng-disabled="disableSelect"
                        data-ng-change="onChange(item)"
                        ng-init="selectedItem = items[0]"></select>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class=" btn btn-info blue-tooltip"
                            data-ng-disabled="disableAddButton"
                            data-ng-click="addSelectedItem()">
                        <span class=" fa fa-plus"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>  


  app.directive('dcLookupDropdown', [function () {
       //Usage:
       //<div data-dc-lookup-dropdown
       //     title="Units:"
       //     items="vm.mylist"
       //     selected-item="vm.selectedItem"
       //     selected-items="vm.selectedItems">
       //</div>
        var directive = {
            controller: ['$scope', lookupDropDownController]
            ,scope:  {
                "title":"@"
                ,"items": "="
                ,"selectedItem": "="
                ,"selectedItems": "="
            }
            ,restrict: 'A'
            ,replace: true
            ,templateUrl: 'app/templates/dc-lookupDropDown-template.html'
        };

        return directive;


        function lookupDropDownController($scope) {

            $scope.addSelectedItem = addSelectedItem;
            $scope.removeSelectedItem = removeSelectedItem;
            $scope.onChange = onChange;
            $scope.disableAddButton = true;
            $scope.disableSelect = false;

            activate();

            function activate() { }

            function addSelectedItem() {
                $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.selectedItem);

                _disableOption($scope.items, $scope.selectedItem);

                //sets dropdown back to nullo object
                $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
                $scope.disableAddButton = shouldDisableAddButton();
                $scope.disableSelect = shouldDisableSelect();
            }

            function onChange(item) {
                $scope.disableAddButton = shouldDisableAddButton();
            }

            function shouldDisableAddButton() {
                return ($scope.selectedItem.id == 0);
            }

            function shouldDisableSelect() {
                return ($scope.selectedItems.length == $scope.items.length - 1);
            }

            function removeSelectedItem(item) {
                $scope.selectedItem = item;

                for (var idx = $scope.selectedItems.length; idx--;) {
                    if ($scope.selectedItems[idx].id == item.id) {
                         $scope.selectedItems.splice(idx, 1);
                    }
                }
                _enableOption($scope.items, $scope.selectedItem);

                //sets dropdown back to nullo object
                $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
                $scope.disableAddButton = shouldDisableAddButton();
                $scope.disableSelect = shouldDisableSelect();
            }

            function _disableOption(itemList, selectedItem) {
                if (selectedItem !== null) {
                    angular.forEach(itemList, function (item) {
                        if (item.id == selectedItem.id) {
                            item.selected = true;
                            return item;
                        }
                        return selectedItem;
                    }, selectedItem);
                };
            };

            function _enableOption(itemList, selectedItem) {
                if (selectedItem !== null) {
                    var foundItem = angular.forEach(itemList, function (item) {
                        if (item.id == selectedItem.id) {
                            item.selected = false;
                            return item;
                        }
                        return selectedItem;
                    }, selectedItem);
                };
            };
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: What does the `itemdetail` controller look like? The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is if `vm.myList` is somehow a reference to a list that is being shared by your controller instances.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show what is happening with your code?

Comment: I will add the fiddler tonight :-). Thanks!

Comment: Still working on the fiddler, can't seem to get the directive with the select to bind. When I get it working I will post a link.

Comment: Ok I have a solution... I can solve this issue with angular.copy. Is this a bad solution, will it eat up to much memory on the client? They are small lists under 50 items.

Comment: The angular.copy works on this sample but causes issues with hot towel. I get a maximum range error on the get look up methods. So back to the drawing board.